# Micronaut Consul Client and Retry support

Tags: java, micronaut, consul

Does Discovery Client in Micronaut support retry pattern when loading configuration from Consul?

I couldn't find examples in the documentation: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#distributedConfiguration or project sources.
The only component where retry is supported is Micronaut Consul Service Discovery.

However there are use-cases when retry is needed for Consul Config. And Spring Cloud Consul supports it from the beginning.
So if it's not natively supported are there any ways to provide custom user-defined solution?

Thanks,
Sergiy

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box no, but it is simple to customise since the `ConsulConfigurationClient` uses the `ConsulClient` implementation which is another bean.

You can replace this bean with the following to apply whatever retry policy works for you:

```java
    @Client(id = ConsulClient.SERVICE_ID, path = "/v1", configuration = ConsulConfiguration.class)
    @Requires(beans = ConsulConfiguration.class)
    @BootstrapContextCompatible
    @Replaces(AbstractConsulClient.class)
    @Retryable(attempts = "5", delay = "1s")
    abstract class MyConsulClient extends AbstractConsulClient {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, @greame-rocher. However this class doesn't replace existing AbstractConsulClient (as I see from debugging) and terminates application immediately without retry.